# java xml validation: getting a better validation error description

Tags: java, xml

I am using javax.xml.validation.Validator from SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI) to perform XSD validation.

I would like to be able to get a better error message back for validation errors.
All I currently get is:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'TypeCode'.`

Is it possible to have the error print out which element or xml fragment is failing validation?

*Edit: I am using the standard java6 xml parsers
*Edit2: Sorry for not mentioning - I am using JAXB to read the XML with a contenthandler and a listener (due to the XML being > 1GB most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not with the validator (maybe one Xerces uses?) you are using. There are other validators, Sun's Multi-Schema Validator for example, but I don't know if any have particularly good error messages for schema validation.
For DTD validation Woodstox has better exception messages, but for XML Schema validation it relies on MSV.

However; even the default parser/validator should be able to give you actual error location (or something nearby). If not with error message, you should at least be able to keep track of preceding locations by registering SAX listener, since validator you are using is using SAX API.

Comment: All I get is an error message similar to what I provided above with no clue to which element has the problem. :-(

Comment: With MSV? Do you at least get location information, or not even that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering an ErrorHandler with your Validator and accessing the details on the corresponding SAXParseException?

Comment: Right, you can use Document.normalizeDocument() after setting an error handler, and get pointers to the elements with errors. The only problem with this solution is that normalizeDocument() will change your DOM document. You could clone it before, but then you have to find a way to link cloned elements.